# Update a model column value by clicking a link ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.2, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a `servicebooking` model and I am trying update its `accept_booking` column with a value of 1 when the following link is clicked in my `servicebooking` show view:

```
<%= link_to 'Accept this booking', acceptbooking_servicebooking_path(@servicebooking) %>
```

I get the following error:

```
undefined method `acceptbooking_servicebooking_path' for #<#<Class:0x5a35e98>:0x5a2bbf0>
```

Below I have declared the route in routes.rb

```
get 'acceptbooking', to: 'servicebookings#acceptbooking'
```

I have the following acceptbooking method in my servicebookings controller:

```
def acceptbooking
    render nothing: true
    @servicebooking = Servicebooking.find(params[:id])
    @servicebooking.update_attribute(:accept_booking, 1) 
  end
```

**my Routes.rb**

```
Appa::Application.routes.draw do
  devise_for :users
  devise_for :views
  get "welcome/index"
  # The priority is based upon order of creation: first created -> highest priority.
  # See how all your routes lay out with "rake routes".

  # You can have the root of your site routed with "root"
  root 'welcome#index'
  get 'myevents', to: 'events#myevents'
  get 'myvenues', to: 'venues#myvenues'
  get 'myservices', to: 'services#myservices'
  get 'make_available', to: 'services#make_available'
  get 'myservicebookings', to: 'servicebookings#myservicebookings'
  get 'acceptbooking', to: 'services#acceptbooking'

  #match 'acceptbooking', to: 'servicebookings#acceptbooking', via: [:get, :post]
  resources :events do
     resources :comments

   end

   resources :users do
     resources :events
   end

   resources :venues do
     resources :comments do
       collection do
         post :venuec
       end
     end
   end

   resources :services do
     resources :comments do
       collection do
         post :servicec
       end
     end
   end

   resources :servicebookings do
     resources :services
   end
end
```

Can anyone see where Iam going wrong here? Thanks guys.

Comment: Can you post your routes file.

Comment: Hey vinodadhikary I have updated my post

Comment: Thanks vinodadhikary, that worked now I get the following error: Couldn't find Servicebooking without an ID in the following line @servicebooking = Servicebooking.find(params[:id]) in the controller method, i tried putting a hidden id field???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this: `get 'acceptbooking/:id', to: 'servicebookings#acceptbooking', as: 'acceptbooking_servicebooking'`

Answer (score 0):

With just the route definition (from your route file):

```
get 'acceptbooking', to: 'servicebookings#acceptbooking'
```

the name of the route will be `acceptbooking` so you should be using `acceptbooking_path`.  But based on your `<%= link_to 'Accept this booking', acceptbooking_servicebooking_path(@servicebooking) %>`, it appears like you want a url like `/servicebookings/:service_booking_id/acceptbooking`.  If this is the case then you should update your route definition to:

```
resources :servicebookings do
  resources :services

  # Move the following line here from the top.
  get 'acceptbooking', to: 'servicebookings#acceptbooking'
end
```

And this will give you `servicebooking_acceptbooking_path` (Note the order of servicebooking and acceptbooking here).